# Conditions, so the operator in L^2 is a projection

Tags: functional-analysis, projection

Given that $r(x) $is nonnegative smooth function satisfying $r(x)+r(-x)=1$ with support $(-1,\infty)$ and$$(Pf)(x)=r(x)f(x)+t(x)f(-x)$$ from $L^2$ to $L^2$ is a projection , i.e. $P$ is idempotemt and self adjoint, what is a relation between $t$ and $r$? Can we prove that $r(x)=\pm t(x)$
This was from the book where the condition $t(x)=\sqrt{r(x)r(-x)}$ was given without the proof.

Using $P^2=P$ I can conclude that $r(x)r(-x)=t(x)t(-x), but I am not sure how to use the fact that the operator is self adjoint.

Comment: Did you calculate $P^2$?

Comment: Yes, but it was not enough

Comment: You should show us the work you've done.

Comment: Being idempotent is enough for being a projection. If you need also self-adjointness it means you're looking for an orthogonal projection with respect to the $L^2$ inner product

Comment: Yes, as @DavideL comments, often "projection" just means idempotent, ... yet one might be subliminally thinking of _orthogonal_ projections... Depends on context.